# PHPUnit: How do I create a function to be called once for all the tests in a class?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a PHPUnit test case class (consisting of some test functions). I would like to write a `oneTimeSetUp()` function to be called once for all my tests in the class (unlike the standard `setUp()` function which is called once for each test in the class). In other words, I'm looking for a PHPUnit equivalent to the [JUnit `@BeforeClass` annotation](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html).

Same question with a `oneTimeTearDown()` function.

Is it possible to do so in PHPUnit?

Comment: I fully understand the need to do this sometimes for performance. It's recommended to avoid this if possible so you're not sharing state between tests.

Comment: @Greg: I agree. Still, there are situations where it's better to initialize once for all the tests (to establish a connection to the db, for instance).

Comment: I try to avoid requiring a DB server by mocking Zend_Db / PDO adapter in my datamapper, I then run assertions on the SQL my classes produce. I appreciate sometimes its unavoidable for functional / end-to-end tests.

Comment: @Greg: The tests I'm working on are functional tests. They test the highest level, the end-product.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Take a look at `setUpBeforeClass()` from [section 6](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html#fixtures.more-setup-than-teardown) of the PHPUnit documentation.

For the one time tearDown you should use `tearDownAfterClass();`.

Both this methods should be defined in your class as static methods.

Comment: I was about to write the same thing... Your answer is THE answer

Comment: Is there any non-static alternative?

Comment: @Martijn unfortunatelly right now there isn't a method for that in phpunit. Fortunatelly you can override this missing feature by using some "initialized" flag or lazy loading in setUp(). It's still get executed before each test, but does nothing if test class has been already initialized.

Comment: For `setUp`, fencing with a flag `initialized` works, but not for `tearDown` because you don't know which is the last test.

Comment: note that this only works if processIsolation is not true in xml or parameters. So, Is there any other option to setupBeforeClass() ?

Comment: @Martijn maybe the constructor and destructor?

Answer (score 30):

`setUpBeforeClass()` is the way to do this if all of your tests are literally contained within a single class.

However, your question sort of implies that you may be using your test class as a base class for multiple test classes. In that case setUpBeforeClass will be run before each one. If you only want to run it once you could guard it with a static variable:

```php
abstract class TestBase extends TestCase {

  protected static $initialized = FALSE;
  
  public function setUp() {
    
    parent::setUp();

    if (!self::$initialized) {
      // Do something once here for _all_ test subclasses.
      self::$initialized = TRUE;
    }
  }

}
```

A final option might be a [test listener](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener).

Comment: This was helpful, but remember to add `parent::setUp();` as the first line of the `public function setUp()`.

Comment: This is what I said 2 days before you and somehow you're getting all the up-votes. I wonder why.

Comment: @cprn Because maintainers don't like using `@before` comment-way, or anything that hides code-flow in comments.

Comment: @Top-Master Yeah, I don't think that's the reason - my example used to contain `setUp()` as well before edits. There's a ton of people boosting their SO content with fake accounts before sending resume or a job interview. AFAIR it was my suspicion back in a day. Nowadays I couldn't care less.

Comment: @cprn Now I get you: 1. someone did copy your answer 2. and instead of that "copy" getting deleted by moderator, they even got more upvotes 3. Finally, you was forced to edit to avoid being a duplicate (even though you was the first to answer).

Comment: @Top-Master Exactly. On top of that OP specifically didn't want to use `setUp()` because it's called before every test so I addressed that in my answer and wanted to use `setUpBeforeClass()` but while writing the code I used `setUp()` out of habit. I later fixed that but this guy didn't even notice the mistake so his code still uses `setUp()`. It's kind of funny how obvious it is he copied my answer.

Comment: lifesaver - I can't believe how misleading the documentation is about this. I was pulling my hair out wondering why  `setUpBeforeClass` was running multiple times when the docs said it would only run once. Not clear at all.

Answer (score 14):

I came to this page with the same question, however the accepted answer is ran on all classes, and for me was not the correct answer.

If you are like me, your first "Integration test" is to clear out the DB, and run migrations. This gets yourself at a database baseline for all test. I am constantly changing migration files at this point, so setting up the baseline is truly part of all tests.

The migration takes a while, so I do not want it run on all tests.

Then I needed to build up the database testing each piece. I need to write an order test, but first I need to create some products and test that, then I need to test an import fuction.

So, what I did is SUPER easy, but not explained extremely well on the internet. I created a simple test to setup the database. Then in your phpspec.xml file add a testsuite....

```
<testsuite name="Products">
    <file>tests/in/SystemSetupTest.php</file>
    <file>tests/in/ProductTest.php</file>
    <file>tests/in/ProductImportTest.php</file>
</testsuite>
```

And  in the the SystemSetupTest.php ....

```
class SystemSetupTest extends ApiTester
{

    /** @test */
    function system_init()
    {
        fwrite(STDOUT, __METHOD__ . "\n");
        self::createEM(); //this has all the code to init the system...
    }
}
```

Then execute it like:

phpunit --testsuite Products

In the end, its a ton easier. It will allow me to build up my system correctly.

Additionally I am using laravel 5. When using `setUpBeforeClass()` I end up with bootstrap issues, which I am sure I can fix, but the method I use above works perfect.

Comment: Better than that run tests like so: `./artisan migrate --datebase CONNECTION_NAME && ./vendor/bin/phpunit`. Not a big deal if you use your shell's command history.

Comment: @x-yuri how come, mate? if you run it locally with DatabaseRefresh trait, you are killing your local db first.
running artisan locally would run on local .env file, then the unit tests would run on test db as it is flagged in phpunit.xml as testing env with all the consequences, this approach is not sustainable.
bootstrap file is the proper place to enclose your custom code that shall run before all tests, the migrate - seed is the perfect candidate for bootstrap.

Comment: @ValentinRusk Haven't used Laravel in a while, but apparently my idea was that rather than create a test that migrates the db, you can migrate the db before running the tests. No one suggests to kill the local database. Did you notice the `--database` switch? What does `DatabaseRefresh` have to do with `./artisan migrate`?.. And there are a number of ways to hide migrating the db (`npm run test`, `./test`, `make test`, ...). If there's a way to make `phpunit` migrate the db once, that would be a better way. But what I did is suggested a better (in my view) solution than the one in the answer.

Comment: Also it's not clear if the author suggests only migration (`SystemSetupTest.php`), or adding data to the database as well. If both, I don't really like the idea, but can't rule out that it might make sense in some cases.

Answer (score 9):

The `bootstrap` option can be used on these cases.

You can call it from the command line

```
phpunit --bootstrap myBootstrap.php
```

Or put it in the XML file, like this:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="myBootstrap.php">
...
</phpunit>
```

Comment: Most of the times for me, this attribute contains `vendor/autoload.php` for loading composer dependencies. Since there can't be multiple bootstrap files, this solution isn't too much suitable

Comment: @Chris You can require `vendor/autoload.php` from the bootstrap file though. For example `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: This is the right answer!
autoloader to go into bootstrap with additional custom code to be run before tests, like setting up your application, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on accepted answer:

None of the `setUpBeforeClass()`, `tearDownAfterClass()`, `@beforeClass`, `@afterClass` runs in the object context (static methods). You can work around that restriction by guarding any `@before` code with a static property instead, like so:

```php
class MyTest extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    private static $ready = false;

    /**
     * @before
     */
    protected function firstSetUp()
    {
        if (static::$ready))
            return;

        /* your one time setUp here */

        static::$ready = true;
    }
}
```

It can't be used for `@after`, however, because there's no way of saying when the last test was called.